# dcef3 - Google Maps welcome always showing

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, chromium-embedded, tchromium

Whenever I navigate to maps.google.com via my dcef3 instance (TChromium), the "welcome" bit always appears over the top.  Can I turn this off somehow with some setting?  If I go to maps.google.com in Chrome or Firefox, it doesn't appear.

I thought it may have been something to do with cookies maybe, so tried setting CefPersistSessionCookies to true but no luck.  Maybe I need to set an Option property with TChromium or handle some other event?  I have made no other changes to the default values for TChromium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I needed to have a cache_path set (CefCache).  According to doco:

> **cache_path** The location where cache data will be stored on disk. If
>   empty an in-memory cache will be used for some features and a
>   temporary disk cache will be used for others. HTML5 databases such as
>   localStorage will only persist across sessions if a cache path is
>   specified.

So it seems (almost obviously to me now) that cache is needed.